# Standard linux utility to combine files without shell

Tags: linux

I'm trying to append the contents of one file onto another existing file. This is trivial with a shell. I'm trying to do it in a single command without a shell. Is this possible?

I basically want to run:

```
cat file2 >> file1
```

Unfortunately, the environment I'm executing in is not a shell and therefore does not support the `>>` operator.

Is there some relatively standard linux tool that would do this, besides just using a shell like:

```
sh -c "cat file2 >> file1"
```

EDIT: I'm looking for a one liner I can put in a systemd service `ExecStart=` directive. Yes, the variant I posted above works, I just think it's hacky.

I'm surprised there isn't a tool to do this exactly.

I could also make a file `my-script.sh` that I call from systemd that does what I want. But that's an extra file and feels even more "hacky" than the first possible solution.

If there is no standard tool that does this, then I guess the "answer" to my question would be "no".

Comment: Shell is a standard unix tool. If you are not executing in a shell, then run a shell exactly as your second code snipped is.

Comment: What environment are you executing in?

Comment: Updated summary to include environment details

Comment: No, it's not *hacky* to do `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/bin/cat %u >> /path/to/myfile'`. And creating dedicated script is even a clean way for doing this too!!

Comment: @F.Hauri sounds like a difference of opinions. I think it's hacky because bash can read certain config files or environment variables that change its behavior, even when started as a non-login prompt. Of course, invoking bash with `sh` makes bash not load the init files, but you've got to read deep in the docs to see that. Regardless, it still feels hacky to me. I'm just looking for an alternative.

Comment: @CameronTacklind `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` are two different binaries tools! You could use `dash` as *standard shell* and keep `bash` for local scripts only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but you can use `dd`:

```
dd if=file2 of=file1 conv=notrunc oflag=append
```

If you are not using GNU dd that supports `oflag=append`, you can specify a byte offset manually:

```
dd if=file2 of=file1 bs=1 seek=insert_size_of_file1_in_bytes_here
```

Comment: *＋1*. I did not know [dd is a Posix command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html).